# Assigning a keyboard shortcut to Accumulate button in Texture Paint Mode

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to assign Shift+A to toggle Accumulate in Texture Paint Mode, I'm not sure how to do it and my attempts so far haven't worked.

Does anyone know how it's done?

Thank you

[image: Accumulate button]

[image: My attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the first box type wm.context_toggle.

This will open up another box in the bottom, Context Attributes. Type:

"tool_settings.image_paint.brush.use_accumulate" to set the property you want to toggle.